Правильная ли структура объекта для multi menu?
Хочу сделать multi menu как в телеграмме. Где у нас список меню «данные и память» в нем ещё одно меню, ещё одно или просто checkbox и т.д. Подскажите пожалуйста, верный ли я подход выбрал? Указание компонента я выбрал по той причине, что разделы у нас могут быть абсолютно разные + некоторые разделы могут грузиться от сервера.
Искал в интернете пример реализации такого меню, но такое ощущение, что его вообще нет :)
Но есть маленькая проблема. А как собственно передавать пропсы и данные от сервера в компонент? :)
Вот передавать тему и язык я примерно представляю как буду делать. У нас будет стейт form в котором будет объект данных по id. Также передавать и пропсы + данные от сервера?

[ 
  { 
    sectionTitle: "Настройки", 
    items: [ 
      // Для types: input & link мы будем показывать иконку arrow-right 
      { id: "theme", label: "Смена темы", type: "input", children: "ComponentTheme" }, 
      { id: "language", label: "Язык", type: "input", children: "ComponentLanguage" }, 
      { id: "wifi", label: "Wi-Fi", type: "toggle" }, // type toggle - это checkbox 
    ] 
  }, 
  { 
    sectionTitle: "Какое-то меню", 
    items: [ 
      {  
        label: "Пункт 1",  
        type: "link",  
        // Если у нас children обьект, значит в нем другое меню, а если string - Component 
        children: [ 
          { 
            id: “1-1”,
            label: "Пункт 1 пункта 1", 
            type: "toggle" 
          }, 
          { 
            label: "Пункт 2 пункта 1", 
            type: "link", 
            children: "Component1-2" 
          } 
        ]  
      } 
    ] 
  } 
]


